# Android custom WebView is failing to find javascript functions defined in loaded HTML

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, android-webview

I have an Android WebView. I pass HTML to it (as a String). This HTML contains some basic javascript.

Upon load, the HTML attempts to call a javascript function (defined in the `<head></head>`). This works fine in my browser desktop so I'm sure the HTML/Javascript itself is fine, but it fails to work when I load the same HTML into my WebView.

Here is how I instantiate the WebView:

```
WebView view = new WebView(context);
WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
view.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());
view.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
view.loadData(ARBITRARY_HTML, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

The loaded HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My head hurts from head-desking</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #content
    {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
    function ShowContent()
    {
        document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
    }
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="ShowContent()">
    <div id="content">
    This content should be shown, but isn't!
    </div>
    <div id="other">
    All I see is this content... and that makes me question my self worth.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This produces (on Android only) the runtime javascript error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ShowContent is not defined".

Comment: This is really doing my head in. It's one of those "my eyes are bleeding because I've been over this code so much trying to find the bug" problems. I'm sure I'm just not seeing something simple.

Some have suggested I use jQuery but the javascript I'm attempting to run is so incredibly simple, it seems like a bit of bloat to include an extra 100kb just to solve... and I'm not even sure that is the problem.

Comment: **UPDATE** I did a test and created two buttons `<input type="button" value="Call Function" onclick="ShowContent();"></input><input type="button" value="Execute Directly" onclick="document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';"></input>`. Executing javascript directly by pressing the second button works fine (wtf?) but I'm unable to call the function. I really can't understand what the gotcha is here.

Comment: I have a input field like this <input name="profile_image" style="display:none;" id="profile_image" onChange="fileSelected('profile');" type="file" accept="image/*" /> in this case its not opening my file chooser dialog but when I remove style="display:none;" from the above code its working just fine. How to resolve this. I want to hide the input field (the Browse button) please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an assumption. The `//<!-- ... //-->` technique which is a made up hack for really old browsers is so out of date. Try to remove that.

Comment: You're amazing. That was it. Wow. What's even more interesting to me is that I _swear_ I only put that in after an epic struggle of trying to make everything more "compliant" to try to kick it into action. That was it! Solution found. I would upvote if I had the reputation ;)

Comment: Thanks for accept. You get a upvote from me just for the good questioning. Your second comment update gave me the needed hint. I know some really dirty hacks since I used to work with internet explorer. Hint: Forget them all while working with android ;-)

Comment: Wow, in my case, removing the <!-- helped!

Comment: @Knickedi I have a input field like this <input name="profile_image" style="display:none;" id="profile_image" onChange="fileSelected('profile');" type="file" accept="image/*" /> in this case its not opening my file chooser dialog but when I remove style="display:none;" from the above code its working just fine. How to resolve this. I want to hide the input field (the Browse button) please help

Comment: @QadirHussain Does your question relate to this answer in some way? I would suggest that you open an own question for that. Seems not be the right place to discuss it here.

Comment: @Knickedi yes Look at here please . I have posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064468/file-chooser-dialog-not-opening-in-android-webview-if-displaynone