# File chooser dialog not opening in android webview if "display:none"

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview

Good morning developers

Well I have made an android webview application, I m facing a little issue, I searched alot but couldn't found any valid solution.

Ok. the problem is that. I have a php/Html code like this

```
 <input type="file" name="banner_image" style="display:none;" id="banner_image" onChange="fileSelected('banner');" accept="image/*" />
```

*Notice:* the `style="display:none;"`

I m calling the onclick event of input field from onClick of a `div` via Jquery like this

```
<div class="profile-pic-txt" onClick="openFileDialog('profile');"> Click here to add
        Profile Picture
        <p>200px/200px</p>
      </div>
```

and here is my java-script openFileDialog() function

```
function openFileDialog(test)
{
$("#banner_image").click();
console.log("Test");
}
```

Its not opening my file chooser dialog.

But when i remove this `display:none;` from my above code its just working fine.  I tested this in iPhone its working fine in both conditions but in android webview its not invoking my file chooser dialog while keeping `display:none`.

**Question** 
I have to make my browse button invisible from my webpage as its template/design requirement (`which I have done with display:none`)

and in the last here is my android webview configuration code.

```
private void configureWebview() {

    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(MODE_APPEND);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {

            Log.e("Console Webview",
                    cm.message() + " -- From line " + cm.lineNumber()
                            + " of " + cm.sourceId());

            return true;

        }

        // For Android < 3.0
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            uploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        // For Android 3.0+
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                String acceptType) {
            uploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        // For Android 4.1
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                String acceptType, String capture) {
            uploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

    });

}
```

Just repeating my problem: File chooser is not opening while keeping `display:none` in `<input name="banner_image" style="display:none;" id="banner_image" onChange="fileSelected('banner');" type="file" accept="image/*" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

input file doesn't work if you use `display:none`

just put it outside the viewable area, for example with `position: absolute;left: -500px;`

Comment: Hahahaha thats the best solution, @jcesar you are the handler. thanks